# "With war come deaths" vs "With war comes deaths"

Tags: grammar, verbs, grammatical-number

Which is the correct form of verb here? what is considered the subject in this case?

Comment: Look at the verb. What's doing the action? That's your subject.  The number of the subject rules the number of the verb.

Comment: *Death comes* or *deaths come*. Are you talking about a singular death, the uncountable subject of death, or multiple deaths?

Answer (score 2):

Most native speakers would solve the number agreement by making *death* singular:

> With war comes death.

The statement is terse like an epigram and as such invites the abstraction "death". The plural "deaths" is rather statistical.

Comment: However if you wanted to emphasise the plurality of individual deaths in war you could say "Deaths come with war". Reversing the word order would not change the meaning  but would give "With war come deaths" as the OP suggests. This is structually similar to saying "With this power come responsibilities". Not quite standard but perfectly grammatical.

Comment: @BoldBen:  I'm not concerned in my answer with the *grammaticality* of the alternatives but with the epigrammatic *register*, which plural "deaths" does not fit into.  Emily Dickinson did not write:  *After great pain formal feelings come*.

Answer (score 1):

This is a simple case of a phrase with non standard-word order. This is often done for stylistic, poetic, or rhetorical reasons. The change of word order does not alter the grammar. So you need to look at what the standard word order would be.

The preposition *with* binds tightly to *war* (as they generally do when they are placed immediately before another word), so we know that "with war" is a prepositional phrase. Prepositional phrases can serve many roles, but "with war" can't be a noun phrase, and it's certainly not a verb, so we know that *deaths* is the subject, and "with war" looks to be an adverbial. So, let's put your alternatives in standard word order based on that analysis:

> Deaths come with war

or

> Deaths comes with war

Knowing how to conjugate the verb *to come*, and the fact that *deaths* is plural, we can see that the second (which corresponds with your second example) is incorrect, the first is correct.

It is worth noting the alternative "death comes with war", putting *death* (and thus also the verb *to come*) in the singular. When writing poetically or rhetorically, it is more common to talk about things like 'death' as an abstract, in which case it becomes uncountable and thus grammatically singular. However, there can be very good reasons to talk about *deaths* as events rather than *death* as an abstract.

Answer (score 0):

I would write "with war come death" because I guess you are talking about the general or abstract idea of the war as well as the death. War cause death is perfectly right too, for the same reason.

Comment: Hi Nicole, welcome to EL&U.  Please could you consider extending and improving your answer and back it up with sources?  Read the [tour] to understand what we want here.